# Assign variable and check it within an IF evaluation

Tags: c#, if-statement, variable-assignment

I doubt this can be done but I'll ask anyway since it would make my code much more readable.

I have to control a large string for various substrings and elaborate it in different ways depending on the substring found.

At the moment I have a nested if like

```
position = mystring.IndexOf("my substring")
if (position>0)
{
    position = mystring.IndexOf("somestring", position);
    [...]
}
else
{
    position = mystring.IndexOf("my substring2")
    if (position>0)
    {
        position = mystring.IndexOf("somestring2", position);
        [...]
    }
    else {...}
}
```

The only other way I can think of doing this is double casting the IndexOf function:

```
if (mystring.IndexOf("my substring")>0)
{

    position = mystring.IndexOf("somestring", mystring.IndexOf("my substring"));
    [...]
}
else if (mystring.IndexOf(mysubstring2)>0)
{
    position = mystring.IndexOf("somestring2", mystring.IndexOf("my substring2"));
    [...]
}
else {...}
```

Is there a way to check the `IndexOf()` result and assign it to a variable all within the `if()` statement?

Something on the line of

```
if ((position = mystring.IndexOf("my substring")) AndAlso position > 0) { ... }
```

or any tip on having such a piece of code handled better?

Comment: `if ((position = mystring.IndexOf("my substring")) >= 0) {...}`

Comment: You use `if (position>0)` but maybe you should use `if (position>=0)`, otherwise you exclude the case that the searched string is at the beginning.

Comment: Although I suspect those are placeholders, just a heads up, if "my substring" isn't found then "my substring2" won't be found either.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks, I did it because I know it can never be the very first character.

Comment: @Default Yes, just placeholders

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do it, like so:

```cs
var myString = "Hello World";
int pos;

if ((pos = myString.IndexOf("World")) >= 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pos); // prints 6
}
else if ((pos = myString.IndexOf("Some Other Substring")) >= 0)
{
    // Do whatever
}
```

Note that I'm using `myString.IndexOf(...) >= 0` as the index of the substring could be 0 (i.e starting at the first character), and the `IndexOf` method returns `-1` if none was found

But you could rather just use [`string.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-5.0) like so:

```cs
var myString = "Hello World";

if (myString.Contains("World"))
{
    // Do whatever
}
else if (myString.Contains("Some Other Substring"))
{
    // Do whatever
}
```

This is better if you don't explicitly need the location of the substring, but if you do, use the first one

Comment: Thanks, someone suggested this solution before but it was missing the parentheses which made it throw an error.

Comment: @des yes, that someone was me, and yes I was missing a parenthesis at first, but Rodrigo Rodrigues edited the answer to fix my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you can put it as

```
int position;

if ((position = mystring.IndexOf("my substring")) > 0)
{

    // Note, that you should use position + "my substring".Length if 
    // "somestring" can't be part of previous match
    position = mystring.IndexOf("somestring", position);
    [...]
}
else if ((position = mystring.IndexOf(mysubstring2)) > 0)
{
    position = mystring.IndexOf("somestring2", position);
    [...]
}
else {...}
```

However, I suggest *extracting a method*:

```
private static bool FindMany(string source, out int lastIndex, params string[] toFind) {
  if (null == toFind)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(toFind));

  lastIndex = -1;
  int result = -1;

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
    return false;

  int index = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < toFind.Length; ++i) {
    result = source.IndexOf(toFind[i], index);

    index += toFind[i].Length;

    if (index < 0)
      return false;          
  }

  lastIndex = result;

  return true;
}
```

Which you can use as

```
int position;

if (FindMany(mystring, out position, "my substring", "somestring") {
  // "my substring" found

  if (position >= 0) {
    // "somestring" is found as well; its index - position   
    ...
  }
  else {
    // only "my substring" has been found
  }
}
else if (FindMany(mystring, out position, "my substring2", "somestring2") {
  // "my substring2" found

  if (position >= 0) {
    // "somestring2" is found  
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm quite baffled. In a statement like `position = mystring.IndexOf("my substring") > 0` I'd expect `position` to be given the boolean value of the latter logical operator, not to be first assigned a value and subsequently tested. I'll give this a try, thanks.

Comment: Hm, as I suspected I get a "cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to type 'int'" error

Comment: It was just missing parentheses, that's why it did not work.

Comment: what is this syntax called? I just saw it used for the first time and I can't find out what this evaluate-an-assignment-in-a-conditional is actually called.

Comment: @Carter Canedy: it is just an *assignment operator*: `a = b` assigns `b` to `a` and *returns* value that assigned see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/assignment-operator

Answer (score 0):

Use `Contains()` and, in addition, use `IndexOf()`separately if you really need to have a position by some reason. `if (mystring.Contains("my substring")) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

this does sound like a job for regex with positive lookbehind:
a positive lookbehind makes sure that the string inside `(?<=)` exists prior to the other string

Together with a TryGet..approach with an out parameter it can *almost* become a one liner.

However, [Dmitrys solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67265127/238902) is a tad more future proof, since it accepts multiple input strings to search for. Building that regex could prove unmaintainable

https://dotnetfiddle.net/D5WFyx

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static void Main()
{
    string input = "here is my substring and then somestring";

    int position;
    if (TryGetIndex(input, "(?<=my substring.*)somestring", out position)){
        Console.WriteLine($"somestring index: {position}");
    }
    else if (TryGetIndex(input, "(?<=other substring.*)otherstring", out position)) {
        Console.WriteLine($"otherstring index: {position}");
    }

    bool TryGetIndex(string input, string pattern, out int position){
        var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
        if (match.Success){
            position = match.Index;
            return true;
        }
        position = -1;
        return false;
    }
}
```